# Using map function to load specific sheets of excel file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am using the following code to read multiple excel files from a folder called input into one dataframe for further data processing

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path=os.chdir("input")
files = os.listdir(path) 
df=pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel, files))
```

It has worked great for a while now!  However, now the Excel report files I input have been changed to be multiple worksheets, with the information I want in the worksheet called "RawData".  So I need to pass the "sheet_name='RawData'" argument.

I have tried

```
df=pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel(sheet_name='RawData'), files))
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: read_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'io'
```

Is there a simple way to pass the kwarg for sheet_name while retaining the map function? Or will I have convert the code to loop through my files list

Answer (score 0):

Looked around a bit and found that instead of using the map function I could rely on list comprehension

my dataframe is now created with

```
df=pd.concat(pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name="RawData") for x in files)
```